# Creating buckets on the fly and individually monitoring bandwidth usage

Tags: cakephp, amazon-s3

Using S3, is it possible to create buckets on the fly, programmatically
(per user or per user project), and meter them individually for
bandwidth usage?

I am using CakePHP framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DevPay http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonDevPay/latest/DevPayDeveloperGuide/index.html?WaysToUse.html to do that